# How to insert specific line instead of nth line?

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a comment with timestamps in many files:

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[some_stored_procedure]    Script Date: 07/28/2015 11:01:13 ******/
```

and I would like to replace them with an empty comment

```
/* */
```

I know that the comment is on the 3rd line of every file. I can remove it with `awk '!(NR==3)'` but I would like to keep the line numbers in the files, so I would like to add an empty comment instead. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
awk 'FNR==3{print "/* */";next}1'  file > new_file
```

**Explanation**

`FNR==3{print "/* */";next}` : When the third line of the field is reached, print *void comment* and skip further steps by `next`

`1` : Print current line.

*Inplace* replacement is possible if you have access to a modern `gawk` implementation:

```
gawk -i inplace 'FNR==3{print "/* */";next}1'  file
```

Check: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html

Comment: Alternatively, `perl -i -ple '$_ = "/* */" if $. == 3' file`.

Comment: Yep , that would be my chosen tool for inplace replacement @melpomene

Answer (score 3):

(c)hange the line 3

```
sed '3 c\
/* */' YourFile > NewFile
```

or

```
sed '3 s#.*#/* */#' YourFile > NewFile
```

maybe add some security

```
sed '3 { \#^[[:blank:]]*/[*]\{1,\}# c\
       /* */
       }' YourFile > NewFile
```

Change the line 3 if start with `/****`

Comment: `sed '3 c /* */'` is much more straightforward... thanks